# From zip to seq with SPARK

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hdfs, out-of-memory

I receive a zip-archive "2018-06-26.zip" each day with a size of approx. 250 Mb compressed, containing 165-170.000 small XML files (Kb's). I load the zip-archive into HDFS (avoiding the small files problem), and using SPARK to extract them from the zip (zip's are not splittable), making a Paired RDD, with the filename as key, and the content as value and save them as a Sequence-file through a paired RDD. Everything runs smooth with a small zip-archive containing only 3 XML-files for testing purposes, but when I feed it the big archive I get

```
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
   at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
   ...
   ...
```

I'm running on Cloudera Quickstart VM: CDH 5.13.3 (HDFS: 2.60, JDK: 1.7.0.67, SPARK: 1.6.0, Scala 2.10)

I haven't run it on a full-blown cluster yet, as I wanted to be sure that my code is correct before deploying it...

The garbage collector keeps running OOM with overhead limit exceeded. I know about raising the amount of memory for the driver  and Java Heap Space, but I'm suspecting my approach is sucking up too much memory.... Monitoring the memory use, does not reveal any memory-leak though....

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipInputStream}
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream
import scala.collection.mutable
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("ZipToSeq")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
var xml_map = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
sc.binaryFiles("/user/cloudera/test/2018-06-26.zip", 10).collect
   .foreach { zip_file : (String, PortableDataStream) =>
    val zip_stream : ZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zip_file._2.open)
    var zip_entry : ZipEntry = null
    while ({zip_entry = zip_stream.getNextEntry; zip_entry != null}) {
      if (!zip_entry.isDirectory) {
        val key_file_name = zip_entry.getName
        val value_file_content = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(zip_stream, "iso-8859-1").getLines.mkString("\n")
        xml_map += ( key_file_name -> value_file_content )
      }
      zip_stream.closeEntry()
    }
    zip_stream.close()
  }
val xml_rdd = sc.parallelize(xml_map.toSeq).saveAsSequenceFile("/user/cloudera/2018_06_26")
```

Any help or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested when the error happens? After 1.000, 10.000 or 100.000 files?
When you unzip the file, how much space does it use?

Comment: Hi @boje, thx for commenting.... i found the culprit to be the size of partitions (!) .... so my fix was in the end to optimize size/number of partitions by altering this number:

sc.parallelize(xml_map.toSeq, **150**).saveAsSequenceFile("c:/temp/today")

resulting of 150 partitions each approx 18 Mb, or 50 partitions each approx 50 Mb, or anything there in between. It depends on the individual task, trading size for speed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import java.util.zip.{ZipEntry, ZipInputStream}
import org.apache.spark.input.PortableDataStream
import scala.collection.mutable
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("ZipToSeq")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
var xml_map = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
sc.binaryFiles("/user/cloudera/test/2018-06-26.zip").collect
   .foreach { zip_file : (String, PortableDataStream) =>
   val zip_stream : ZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zip_file._2.open)
   var zip_entry : ZipEntry = null
   while ({zip_entry = zip_stream.getNextEntry; zip_entry != null}) {
      if (!zip_entry.isDirectory) {
      val key_file_name = zip_entry.getName
      val value_file_content = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(zip_stream, "iso-8859-1").getLines.mkString("\n")
      xml_map += ( key_file_name -> value_file_content )
   }
   zip_stream.closeEntry()
  }
  zip_stream.close()
}
val xml_rdd = sc.parallelize(xml_map.toSeq, 75).saveAsSequenceFile("/user/cloudera/2018_06_26")
```

Original zip file 325 Mb containing 170.000 XML files 
Resulting in 75 partitions, each approx. 35 Mb. In total ~ 2.5 Gb
Run-time locally on my Windows PC: 1.2 minutes :-)